# In Excel increasing the digit value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to get Excel to increase a number by 1 digit when an alpha character is part of the "number". Example: HH-floor2-roomOPE-VSP1 increase to HH-floor2-roomOPE-VSP50.

Is there a way for this entire string of numeric and alpha characters to be inserted in one cell and Excel increase the ending digits by 1?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How did you get from VSP1 to VSP50? An example with more of your data and expected output would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Just right click and drag the bottom right corner of the cell, and select "fill series" to increment by 1.

[image]